# How to stop PHPStorm from automatically refactoring my code

Tags: refactoring, phpstorm, automated-refactoring

I renamed one of my files and phpstorm asked if I wanted to do a refactor on my project.  I accidentally clicked yes to "Refactor", and it changed a bunch of the variable names in a handful of random files in my project.  Not a big deal.  I'm using GIT so I just reverted those files.  However, now every time I revert those files, phpStorm automatically refactors them again.  It sometimes refactors the files instantly, and other times it won't refactor them for a few hours, but it's constantly changing them making it really hard to get any work done as it continues to break my project.

How can I stop this refactor process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me:

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...`